# Ruby: nil.to_sym raises exception, why?

Tags: ruby

```
nil.to_i => 0
nil.to_a => []
nil.to_h => {}
nil.to_s => ''
nil.to_sym => undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a specific reason why this is not implemented? I'd expect this behavior:

```
nil.to_sym => :''
```

This would be consistent with the rest. Should I make a feature request at ruby-lang.org?

Comment: (I don't really understand why people are downvoting this. It's a legit question, I haven't insulted anyone.)

Comment: You're probably getting down votes because only Matz can answer this question. There is no Ruby specification let alone an annotated specification with justifications for various decisions. Even `NilClass#to_h` is a fairly recent addition.

Answer (score 2):

I think implementing nil.to_sym => :'' in Ruby will be semantically incorrect.

The "to_sym" method returns the Symbol corresponding to a string, creating the symbol if it did not previously exist. Considering that nil is not an instance of String and rather is an instance NilClass, it fulfills the specifications set by its creators.

I hope this answers your query.

Comment: And yet, it still feels wrong. The fact that the specification says that it shouldn't do it, doesn't mean that it shouldn't. Maybe the specification should be changed. (At least I know I'm going to change this behavior for my ruby build).

Comment: Yes you can do that, but do notice that these methods are instance specific and to_sym implementation is very specific to the String instance only. So be careful and good luck

Comment: Btw, the documentation on String#to_i says: `Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an integer base base (between 2 and 36). Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at the start of str, 0 is returned. This method never raises an exception when base is valid.`. This 'special' behavior when there is no valid number at the start of str could by applied to `to_sym` too.

Comment: @Mat: You are confusing the single-letter and three-letter conversion methods. Single letter means "can be represented as". Surely, an empty `String` can be represented as the number 0. Three letter means "IS-A". An empty `String` is not the number 0, which is why you will notice that `String` defines `to_i`, but *not* `to_int`. In fact, you will notice that only very few classes actually define `to_int`. The same applies to `to_sym`, with the added caveat that there is no corresponding single-letter version, since the fact that `Symbol`s are their own representation is one of the defining …

Comment: features and thus the idea that something can be represented as a `Symbol` is not very useful.

Comment: Thanks Jörg. This is the real explanation I was looking for. I'll sleep better tonight.